# Question concerning the definition of limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

In the definition of limit of a sequence, it doesn't state the uniqueness of the limit. We have to prove, if the sequence converges,the limit is unique.

Why don't we just add the uniqueness in the definition of limit? Why there are some definition which already include the uniqueness, but not proving it? (I can't immediately think one, so I'm not really sure about if there exists such definition.)

Comment: Why define some property if it will be implied anyway? Also, in topology, limits are not necessarily unique.

Comment: The reason one might not add uniqueness to the definition limit of a sequence (in a particular space, in this case a Hausdorff one) is that one doesnt *have* to. In other words, the limit of a sequence in a Hausdorff space is always unique, so adding that to the definition would be superfluous. We don't like that in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.

The definition of limit, as we see in metric spaces like the real numbers, is often inherited from the definition of limit for topological spaces. Topological spaces have nothing but a sets and a clasification of "open" subsets  of  it. The definition of limit changes for topological spaces:

> A sequence $\{ x_n\}$ converges to a point $x$ if given any open set $U$ such that $x\in U$, there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N \implies x_n \in U$.

Now, the reason why this works for metric spaces is because metric spaces have a property called Hausdorff.

> For every two points $x$ and $y$ in a metric space, there is an open set around $x$ and an open set around $y$, which don't intersect each other.

You can prove this very easily. But now, suppose that some space is not Hausdorff. Then, there will be some two points $x$ and $y$ which can't be separated by disjoint open neighbourhoods.

By definition, in this space, whenever a sequence will converge to $x$, it will also converge to $y$! That is because, any open set containing $x$ also contains $y$ (otherwise they could have been separated), hence if you are given an open set $U$ around $x$, then $y \in U$, and if $\{ x_n\} \to x$, then $x_n$ is eventually in $U$, which means that since $U$ is a neighbourhood of $y$, $\{ x_n\} \to y$ also!

Thus, your non-acquiantance with non-Hausdorff spaces is leading you to believe the limit is unique. Indeed, construction of non-Hausdorff spaces is very easy, and as  you will realize, many sequences here will have different number of limits. It won't be right to talk of a limit then, it would be correct to talk of a set of limit points, in some sense.

---

To give the most trivial example of a non-Hausdorff topological space, consider $\mathbb R$, with the topology given by $\{\emptyset, \mathbb R\}$ as the only empty sets. This is called the indiscrete topology, because it does not differentiate between points : given any two points $x,y \in \mathbb R$, there is only one open set which contains either, therefore you cannot find open sets which separate these two.

Now, let us fix any sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $\mathbb R$ and any constant $b \in \mathbb R$. By definition of convergence in a topological space,  it is sufficient that $\{a_n\}$ eventually lies in any open neighbourhood of $b$. But there is only one neighbourhood, namely $\mathbb R$.

Conclusion : In the indiscrete topology, *every* sequence is convergent and converges to *every* point. There is no question of uniqueness of limit here, when a sequence converges to every point in $\mathbb R$.